# How to install KDE plasma 5.2 on ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: kde, 15.04, plasma

How to install KDE Plasma 5.2 on Ubuntu 15.04? 
Thank you.

Comment: Install kubuntu or kubuntu-desktop `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 3):

Plasma 5.2 is the default on Kubuntu 15.04 .

I highly suggest you boot a kubuntu live usb to test it . If you like it, then you can either do a fresh install of Kubuntu or install it on your 15.04 install.

To install it on your existing install run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingKDE for additional information.